# multiple instances are getting created if tried to use the below code

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-chromedriver

I have  below class `BaseClass.java` which will initialise the driver to use it in TEST classes. I kept the method which fetches driver under annotation `@BeforeClass`.

```
   public class BaseClass{

        static WebDriver driver;

        @BeforeClass
        public void returnDriver(){
            driver = //I have some other method to initiate and return the driver to here 
        }
    }
```

Now , I extended above class into my `Test` Classes

```
public class A extends BaseClass{

    public A(){
        returnDriver();
    }
    @Test
    public void a(){
    }
    @Test
    public void b(){
    }

public class B extends BaseClass{

    public B(){
        returnDriver();
    }
    @Test
    public void a1(){
    }
    @Test
    public void b1(){
    }
```

Used below `testng.xml` to run the TestNG Suite.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
    <suite name="Suite">
      <test name="Test">
        <classes>
          <class name="B"/>
          <class name="A"/>
        </classes>
      </test> <!-- Test -->
    </suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

When i start execution, by default multiple browser instances are running (i.e., if there are 2 test classes, 2 browser instances are launching at a time) though i'm not provided any thread count or parallel execution in testng.xml.

Comment: I suggest you add a `@AfterClass` to your baseclass in which you either close or quit the driver, preferably close.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the driver initialization from @BeforeClass/ returnDriver() method and move it to class level.
2. Use  @AfterClass annotation and close the browser.
3. Use  @BeforeSuite instead of  @BeforeClass

Use any of the above methods.